# Calculating next y using previous y element using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the speed of a vehicle, to plot a graph with time in seconds on x axis, and speed in km/h on y axis. To do that, I need to get the previous calculated y value.

Example: y[x] = y[x-1] * a

```
a = 0,11768
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)    # 0 to 100 seconds
y = a * y[x-1] ??
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Is that possible with numpy, or should I do a loop to iterate over all indexes?

Comment: @GM `a` should be acceleration.

Comment: Note that in python (and other programming languages) you use a decimal _point_, not a comma. If you do `a = 0,11768`, `a` is a tuple; use `a = 0.11768` instead.

Comment: @tobias_k Ok, now have sense...

Comment: Also, I think the calculation should be `y[x] = y[x-1] + a` (plus, not times). Or, just do `y[x] = y0 + a * x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v=v0+at` Assuming your acceleration is constant and `v0=0`there's no need to do what you want simply:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.11768 #is it in m/s^2? I've used m/s^2...
v=[] #velocity at a given time ‹
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)    # 0 to 100 seconds
for i in x: # ‹
    v.append(i*a) #read it as a*t, in fact is t...use i*a*3.6 if you want km/h ‹
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,v,)   
plt.plot(x, v)
plt.ylabel(r'Velocity $(m/sec )$') #note if you want km/h use v.append(i*a*3.6) above
plt.xlabel(r'Time $(sec)$')
plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]
**EDIT:**
As suggest by Joe in his comment you should use `v=a*x` delating the lines marked with `‹`in my code, for a more efficient way to do that!

Comment: Or just `v = a * x`. There's no need for the loop and intermediate list.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation for `y` is wrong. Instead of multiplying the previous speed with the acceleration, you have to *add* the acceleration to that speed. An alternative way would be to multiply the acceleration with the time and add that to some initial speed. This way, you can use a simple list comprehension for `y`.

```
a = 0.11768  # acceleration (note the dot instead of comma!)
y0 = 0       # initial speed at time x = 0
X = numpy.arange(0, 100, 1)
Y = numpy.array([y0 + a * x for x in X])
```

When using Numpy, there's an even simpler way -- thanks to @JoeKington for pointing this out:

```
Y = y0 + a * X  # multiplies each value of X with a and adds y0
```

Comment: You are correct. That seems to be a good way to to it. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI: Don't use list comprehensions for operations like this with numpy arrays. It's much, much less efficient than just doing `Y = y0 + a * X`.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks for the hint, will include it in my answer, if you don't mind. I don't use `numpy` much myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in numpy but I know how you can easily achieve it using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=0.11768

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 100, 1),columns=['X'])
df['Y'] = a*df['X'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0.11768
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
y = [1]
for i in range(1, len(x)-1):
  y.append(a * y[i-1])
```

Comment: If we change from `y.append(a * y[i-1])` to `y.append(a + y[i-1])` (my fault!) and removes `-1` in the for-statement, and set `y = [0]` then it works perfect. Thank you! (I don't have reputation enough to upvote your answer. Sorry.)